# What does | symbol near end of a command do?

Tags: command-line

I came across someone using the command `zcat [filename].gz | less`
to open a file. What does | generally do when it's using in this manner? I've tried googling the question but haven't found the answer yet.

EDIT: actually the answer is here: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Answer (score 2):

`|` is called a *pipe*, its use is to direct the previous command's output to the second's input.
See [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html).
So in your example:

```
zcat [filename].gz | less
```

the outup of `zcat` is *piped* to `less`'s input as if it were standard input. So your command is equivalent to:

```
less `zcat [filename.gz`
```

But be careful that the pipe only works between `stdout` and `stdin`, other file descriptors might give you weird results, or nothing at all.